# When/how to set the inbound or outbound course when intercepting a VOR for a DME hold?

Tags: holding

I have question for holding pattern.

As I know, when I do DME holding I have to intercept VOR radial and decide entry.

However, when I do this I am so confused and do not know how I can select inbound or outbound course.

For example, One instruction is [Hold SE 325R ABC VOR 13 DME Left]

In this case, my instructor says "try to intercept outbound course 145 and make a holding."

However, another instruction is [Hold NW 330R ABC VOR 12 DME]

In this case, my instructor says "set inbound course 150 and make a holding."

In both cases, the position of aircraft was NW from the ABC VOR, and my heading was 150 and distance was almost 18 DME from the ABC VOR.

This is what I confuse that first instruction was setting outbound, but second instruction was setting inbound course for intercepting the radial.

Could you let me know how I can figure out when I set inbound course or outbound course for intercept one for DME holding?

*I use G1000 which has HSI.

Thank you for your work and time!

Answer (score 2):

Below is a picture possibly showing what your instructor may be telling you. (based on the information you have given in your question)

[image]

Comment: than you! but I am still wondering how can I figure out selecting radial which is inbound or outbound because as I understand I have to select the course before intercepting course dme holding.

Comment: @MunPark -Remember that all radials are labeled as they exist "outbound" from the VOR ("course" can be the same as the radial or direct opposite). The "outbound" crs of 145 on the parallel entry takes you toward the VOR before you turn back to the 13 dme fix after a minute (you will be on the 325R when established in the hold). The "inbound" crs is the direct entry to the fix. When established in the hold you will be on the 330R but your crs will be 150 (to the station). I think you should ask your CFI to clarify the way he is issuing the holding instructions to you. – 757toga 19 mins ago

Comment: Yeah I'd say holds are _linguistically_ challenging. the biggest thing I learned about holds since _after_ I got my IR was to imagine the radials. You're holding _on_ the one they state. Turning after you pass the station unless you're on an entry